# Gnuplot heatmap coloring error

Tags: colors, gnuplot, heatmap

I have a puzzling issue with heatmapping in gnuplot...
My script have always worked until this bright day, and I cannot figure out why...

The problem is that my heatmap is allright in numbers (as the regions of my heatmap is in the right place with the right data printed on it, but lack of color) but the color is just in the "diagonal" region of it (picture included)

Here is my script which creates the heatmap (I have gnuplot vers. 5.0 patchlvl 3 ):

```
    Set term pngcairo size 680,7000

    unset key
    set view map
    set xtics border in scale 0,0 mirror norotate  offset character 0, 0, 0 autojustify

    set ytics border in scale 0,0 mirror norotate  offset character 0, 0, 0 autojustify

    set ztics border in scale 0,0 nomirror norotate  offset character 0, 0, 0 autojustify

    set nocbtics

    set rtics axis in scale 0,0 nomirror norotate  offset character 0, 0, 0 autojustify
    set title "Paramétertér" 
    set xlabel"s_{scd}"
    set ylabel"s_{scdd}"
    xnumtics = 5
    ynumtics = 125

    set xtics () # clear all tics
    set for [i=0:xnumtics] xtics add (gprintf("%g", 0. + i * 0.01) i)

    set ytics ()
    set for [i=0:ynumtics] ytics add (gprintf("%g",  -0.16 + i * 0.001) i)

    set xrange [ -0.500000 : 4.50000 ] noreverse nowriteback
    set yrange [ -0.500000 : 124.50000 ] noreverse nowriteback
    set cblabel "Rákosodás mértéke (db szimuláció)" 
    set cbrange [ 0.00000 : 30.00000 ] noreverse nowriteback
    set palette rgbformulae 33, 13, 10
    do for [i=0:49]{
    set output 'parameterter_'.i.'.png'
    m = 0.2-(i*0.004)
    set label 2 at -0.65, 125.0
    set label 2 sprintf("mutrata'%g'",m) tc lt 3

    plot 'parameterter'.i.'.txt' using 1:2:3 with image , 'parameterter'.i.'.txt' using 1:2:($3 == 0 ? "" : sprintf("%g",$3) ) with labels
    unset output
    }
```

Here is the picture bellow:
Sorry if its too trivial, and for my bad english too...:)
Thx!

Comment: eyy, I screwed ip the picture upload...:(

here is the picture:http://imgur.com/a/6EwlM

Sorry...

Comment: I don't know how the correct picture should look like, but AFAIK there is an image bug in this gnuplot version, try 5.0.4

Comment: all the "boxes" should be colorized, so like a standard heatmap... all the colors should depend on the numbers written in the boxes, but thanks, I check the newer version

Comment: weeee, thx Christoph!!! It works with patchlvl 4 :))))

http://imgur.com/a/MnWFd